# Live survey tool that allows prepopulating hidden field via URL

Tags: web-apps, survey

My company currently uses [Slido](https://www.sli.do/) during webinars to ask survey questions and show entertaining dynamically-updating results as answers come in.

It's working well except for this drawback:

Our surveys always feature this question: "What email address did you use when registering for this webinar?" People too often mistype their email address or provide one that wasn't actually the email address that they used when registering.

So then we're unable to match their responses to other pieces of data in other systems of ours.

We'd prefer to send an email (from our own custom email system) to each webinar attendee at the scheduled start time of the webinar, and each email message would contain a unique personalized link to the specific survey for that session, *and* within the link we would include this attendee's (confirmed) email address. E.g. the link could be `https://app.sli.do/event/k3dJ85BvgGQUk/live/questions?email=john@example.com`.

We would want the survey system to then invisibly record the email address of that respondent (in a way that does NOT let the respondent change or delete the email address), and then the respondent's answers to the (visible) questions during that session would all be associated with that email address.

**In other words, we're looking for a tool that allows us to ask survey questions in an entertaining way (dynamically instantly updating charts of results while people answer the questions) that also allows us to easily authenticate respondents via URL.**

Alternatively, it would also be acceptable if the unique identifier that we pass to the survey system is something other than an email address. For example, our custom app that is responsible for sending the emails could pass a user ID or a GUID or whatever. It will be a success as long as we can tie responses back to the confirmed email address that we know for a webinar attendee.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclosure: I am one of the developers of PollUnit**

With [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com) you can create various types of polls and surveys. All types allow to collect GET parameters. For this you need to allow list your keys in the "Advanced Step" in the wizard and append the parameters in this format `?key1=value1&key2=value2` to the participant url.

As long as the visitor is not changing the link with the parameters before visiting the poll/survey the user will be associated with the given GET parameters. Even when the user is changing the parameters and revisits the poll/survey the initial parameters win (except the user clears cookies or logs out when using an account).

This feature is available from the paid business plan. Here you find the [price list](https://pollunit.com/en/accounts).

Your use-case sounds like a survey with several steps to me. In stead of our other poll types, surveys do not show results by default. You can publish results in the advanced step. If you publish results the GET params stay hidden to your participants. All other inputs of your users will be visible.

Here you find the [GET param feature announcement](https://pollunit.com/en/posts/162/store-url-parameter-with-survey)